# Reference for proof of "Dedekind's Criterion"?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

It was mentioned to me briefly in passing about a criterion for rings of integers, referred to as Dedekind's Criterion.

The Criterion essentially said that a ring $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ (for $\omega=\sqrt[3]{2}$ for example) is $p$-maximal (in it's fraction field I believe) if and only if the greatest common divisor of certain polynomials reduced modulo $p$ was equal to $1$, (or a constant). These polynomial are related to the prime $p$ in question, but I can't recall how.

I know this is terribly vague, but is anyone aware of a result that goes by Dedekind's criterion that sounds like this? I've been searching for it every, but have had no luck locating it or it's formulation. Does anyone have a possible reference?

Comment: I'm a little confused -- have you googled it?  Quite a few relevant results come up...

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find it on the first page of this [link](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00013-004-1227-4). Also at this [link](http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Math%20Complete/Number%20theory/A%20course%20in%20computational%20algebraic%20number%20theory%20-%20Cohen%20H..pdf), which is pages 305-306 of Henri Cohen, A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory.

Comment: Maybe a more conceptual version of this is about whether or not a ring is _locally_ the whole ring of (local) integers.